# I am trying to execute a code using Matplotlib in Python and getting the below issue while using fill_between() for matplotlib 3.3.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill, between

I am trying to fill the area in the plot where (allDevSalaries >= pythonDevSalaries ). However, after i execute the code it does not show the area being filled. I have provided the code below and the graph it produces. Can anybody help me with this ?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

age = [21,22,23]

allDevSalaries = [12000,13000,13500]

pythonDevSalaries = [13000,12000,14545]

plt.plot(age,allDevSalaries,label='All Dev')

plt.plot(age,pythonDevSalaries,label='Python Dev')

plt.fill_between(age,allDevSalaries,pythonDevSalaries,where=(allDevSalaries >= pythonDevSalaries ),interpolate=True,color='red',label='Above Avg',alpha=0.25)

plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('AGE')

plt.ylabel('SALARY')

plt.title('SALARY per AGE graph')

#plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is the culprit.

From the documentation:

> where: array of bool (length N), optional, default: None

It's expecting an array of booleans, and you're feeding it a single boolean by comparing two python lists.

```
allDevSalaries = [12000,13000,13500]
pythonDevSalaries = [13000,12000,14545]
print(allDevSalaries > pythonDevSalaries) # -> False
```

This code will work:

```
plt.fill_between(age, pythonDevSalaries, allDevSalaries,
                 where=([a >= b for a, b in zip(allDevSalaries, pythonDevSalaries)]),
                 interpolate=True,
                 color='red',
                 label='Above Avg',
                 alpha=0.25)
```

Alternatively, you could use numpy arrays, which return an array of booleans when compared to one another, just like you want.

```
import numpy as np
...
where=(np.asarray(allDevSalaries) >= np.asarray(pythonDevSalaries)) # -> [False True False]
```

[image]